# Excel Theory: Consolidating Data from Multiple Tabs to one tab

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have 4 sheets of data with thousands of rows in each sheet.  There is one column within each sheet that I would like to consolidate into a 5th sheet.  In this column, I'd like to make sure that every name from the previous four sheets is included in one comprehensive list with no repeats.

See a simple example below, but imagine 20,000 rows on each sheet with complex names.  Can anyone think of a method of doing this, that does not require tweaking everytime the inputs change?  I've been trying to use PivotChart Wizard with no luck.

```
Sheet 1     Sheet 2     Sheet 3     Sheet 4      Ideal Sheet 5
Dog          Cat         Fish       Giraffe       Dog
Hamster      Dog         Lhama      Cat           Cat
Giraffe      Elephant    Dog        Fish          Fish
                                                 Giraffe
                                                 Elephant
                                                 Hamster
                                                  Lhama
```

Here is the code I came up with to solve the problem in case anyone is interested.  "Zone & Fam" just specifies the column I'm interested in.

```
Sub GetUniqueZoneFam()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim Lastrow As Long

    Worksheets("Calculation Indv").Range("A:A").ClearContents

    Worksheets("fcst fg").Activate
    Range("Fcst_Fg[Zone & Fam]").Copy
    Worksheets("Calculation Indv").Activate
    Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Worksheets("fcst ps").Activate
    Range("Fcst_PS[Zone & Fam]").Copy
    Worksheets("Calculation Indv").Activate
    Range("A" & Lastrow + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Worksheets("sales fg").Activate
    Range("Sales_FG[Zone & Fam]").Copy
    Worksheets("Calculation Indv").Activate
    Range("A" & Lastrow + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Worksheets("sales ps").Activate
    Range("Sales_PS[Zone & Fam]").Copy
    Worksheets("Calculation Indv").Activate
    Range("A" & Lastrow + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Range("A:A").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    Range("A1").Select

    Worksheets("Calculation Indv").Range("A1").Value = "Zone & Fam"
    Worksheets("Calculation Indv").Range("A1").Font.Bold = True


    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox ("Done!")

End Sub
```

Comment: Copy and paste all of the data into `Sheet5` duplicates and all, then run the [`RemoveDuplicates'](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-removeduplicates-method-excel) method on the column.

Comment: This would work but it is not dynamic and will not automatically update for the user of the model.  I wrote a macro that essentially does this with the click of a button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In vba this would look something like the following (Totally not tested, written outside of VBE, probably riddled with mistakes, definitely will need tweaking to fit your sheet names and columns where your data lives):

```
Dim wsName as String
Dim lastRow as Long
Dim writeRow as Long

'set the row on which we are going to start writing data to "Sheet 5"
writeRow = 1

'Loop though your sheets to copy from
For Each wsName In Array("Sheet 1", "Sheet 2", "Sheet 3", "Sheet 4")

    'determine the last used row in the worksheet we are copying from
    lastRow = Sheets(wsName).Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

    'grab the data
    Sheets(wsName).Range("A1:A" & lastRow).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet 5").Range("A" & writeRow)

    'increment the writeRow
    writeRow = writeRow + lastRow

Next wsName

'Now that all the data is copied, dedup it
Sheets("Sheet 5").Range("A1:A" & writeRow).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1), Header:=xlNo
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  I ended up writing a Macro similar to yours and it is working well.  Appreciate the help

Comment: Awesome to hear it!

Comment: @oryan5000, paste your answer as an answer as well, instead of editing it in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Sub GetUniqueZoneFam()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

```
Dim Lastrow As Long

Worksheets("Calculation Indv").Range("A:A").ClearContents

Worksheets("fcst fg").Activate
Range("Fcst_Fg[Zone & Fam]").Copy
Worksheets("Calculation Indv").Activate
Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Worksheets("fcst ps").Activate
Range("Fcst_PS[Zone & Fam]").Copy
Worksheets("Calculation Indv").Activate
Range("A" & Lastrow + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Worksheets("sales fg").Activate
Range("Sales_FG[Zone & Fam]").Copy
Worksheets("Calculation Indv").Activate
Range("A" & Lastrow + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Worksheets("sales ps").Activate
Range("Sales_PS[Zone & Fam]").Copy
Worksheets("Calculation Indv").Activate
Range("A" & Lastrow + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Application.CutCopyMode = False

Range("A:A").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
Range("A1").Select

Worksheets("Calculation Indv").Range("A1").Value = "Zone & Fam"
Worksheets("Calculation Indv").Range("A1").Font.Bold = True


Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox ("Done!")

End Sub
```